# Checking if a website is online through bash script

Tags: bash, wget

I need a script that checks the url '$site' twice before reporting it as inaccessible?

The script checks this URL and if the URL is not reachable, the script checks it twice after for example 10 seconds, and if the URL is not reachable again, it echoes "no access".

I tried this:

```bash
if wget --spider -S "$site" 2>&1 | grep -w "200\|301\|302" > /dev/null ; then

else
        do
                echo "not access";
        done
fi
```

Comment: `wget` has `-T|--timeout` option/flag, there are a lot of ways to check if the server is up, here is one. `until ping -c3 my_awesome_site.com >/dev/null; do printf 'No luck!\n'; done`

Comment: so thx can you in my code past and show here please, sry and thank you again!! )

Comment: Guys, need 2 check and save every result, 1. if check 1 failed go to check 2 if check 2 failed go else = echo not access. If 1 check reachable go to check 2 if 2 check reachable ok if failed going to check 1 and if then check 2 failed go to = echo not access if check 2 reachable = ok. How i do this? Sipmle ping can't solved this... 8-(

Answer (score 0):

I am do this, because no any other short way found:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN='000000000'
CHAT_ID='(000000000 111111111 22222222)'
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage"
site='https://site.ru'

if wget --spider -S "$site" 2>&1 | grep -w "200\|301\|302" > /dev/null ; then
    echo "Site is up 1: $(date -d 'now + 7 hours' +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')"
else
    sleep 5
    if wget --spider -S "$site" 2>&1 | grep -w "200\|301\|302" > /dev/null ; then
        echo "Site is up 2: $(date -d 'now + 7 hours' +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')"
    else
        for chat in ${CHAT_ID[*]}
        do
           curl -s -X POST $URL -d chat_id=$chat -d text="Сервис временно не доступен"
           echo "Site is down twice: $(date -d 'now + 7 hours' +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')"
       done
    fi
fi
```